# Authentication via IPA fails for FreeBSD 13.2 host

Tags: freebsd, freeipa

ssh authentication to my FreeBSD client oh.oplz.huh is failing. On the FreeBSD client, I see this error in sssd_oplz.yo.log `(Tue Jun 13 15:13:24:459513 2023) [sssd [sss_ini_call_validators] (0x0020): [rule/allowed_sections]: Section [domain/oplz.huh] is not allowed. Check for typos.`
There is no [rule/allowed_sections] in /usr/local/etc/sssd/sssd.conf. In /var/log/messages I see `[sssd[krb5_child[35839]]][35839]: Key table entry not found` and `error: PAM: Authentication error for illegal user ipatest from hdh.oplz.huh` when I attempt to ssh in.

`sssctl config-check` said,
Issues identified by validators: 1
[rule/allowed_sections]: Section [domain/oplz.huh] is not allowed. Check for typos.

I followed this how-to. https://vermaden.wordpress.com/2023/03/29/connect-freebsd-13-2-to-freeipa-idm/

Thanks for any clues.